# Cannot Exit While Loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop

```
float V[1];
float R1[1];
float R2[1];
float R3[1];
char answer;

int again = 0;
while (again != 1) {
    
    printf("Please enter the Voltage and Resister Values below: \n");
    printf("V: ");
    scanf("%f", &V[0]);
    printf("\nR1: ");
    scanf("%f", &R1[0]);
    printf("\nR2: ");
    scanf("%f", &R2[0]);
    printf("\nR3: ");
    scanf("%f", &R3[0]);
    printf("\nYou entered: %f,%f,%f,%f,", V[0],R1[0],R2[0],R3[0]);
    printf("\nContinue(Y/N)?\n");
    if (scanf("%s",&answer) != 'y'){
        again = again +1;
    }
    if (scanf("%s",&answer) != 'Y'){
        again = again+1;
    }
        
}
printf("Exit");
return 0;
```

}

right now it stays stuck once the prompt is answered. how can i get out of this while loop if the user enters anything but y or Y?

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of fields it had read. In your case it's either 1 or 0. `'y'` is the number 121.

Comment: Can you please explain the point of defining single-element arrays for your variables? It almost looks like you were told to use arrays instead of numbered variables, but did not really get the point.

Comment: Do not use "!=" in your string comparison. Look for strcmp function and try again, please; probably it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you

```
int main()
{

    float V[1];
    float R1[1];
    float R2[1];
    float R3[1];
    char answer;
    int again = 0;
    while (again != 1) {

    printf("Please enter the Voltage and Resister Values below: \n");
    printf("V: ");
    scanf("%f", &V[0]);
    printf("\nR1: ");
    scanf("%f", &R1[0]);
    printf("\nR2: ");
    scanf("%f", &R2[0]);
    printf("\nR3: ");
    scanf("%f", &R3[0]);
    printf("\nYou entered: %f,%f,%f,%f,", V[0],R1[0],R2[0],R3[0]);
    printf("\nContinue(Y/N)?\n");
    scanf(" %c",&answer);
    if (answer=='Y'||answer=='y')
    {
        again = again +2;
    }
    else
    {
        again=1;
    }
}
printf("Exit");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'scanf' returns an int, you should compare your char answer with 'y'/'Y'.

Comment: And one definitely doesn't want to call the `scanf` *twice*

Comment: Yes, my program isn't finished im working on the part to keep it going right now is why it looks like this and i am fairly new to C from mips